# Google Sheets API bug

Tags: java, api, oauth, google-sheets

Been following the guide on Googles website. Have my OAuth keys correctly setup but can't get this cell extraction code to work in Java.

Error message is:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type SpreadsheetEntry to CellEntry

```
at com.wow.trading.WOWTrading.MySpreadsheetIntegration.main(MySpreadsheetIntegration.java:51)
```

Code is exactly as Google website and JARs are not missing.

```
package com.wow.trading.WOWTrading;
import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.*;
import com.google.gdata.util.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MySpreadsheetIntegration {
  public static void main(String[] args)
      throws AuthenticationException, MalformedURLException, IOException, ServiceException {

    SpreadsheetService service =
        new SpreadsheetService("MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1");

    // TODO: Authorize the service object for a specific user (see other     sections)

    // Define the URL to request.  This should never change.
    URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL(
        "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");

    // Make a request to the API and get all spreadsheets.
    SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL,
        SpreadsheetFeed.class);
    List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();

    if (spreadsheets.size() == 0) {
      // TODO: There were no spreadsheets, act accordingly.
    }

    // TODO: Choose a spreadsheet more intelligently based on your
    // app's needs.
    SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet = spreadsheets.get(0);
    System.out.println(spreadsheet.getTitle().getPlainText());

    // Get the first worksheet of the first spreadsheet.
    // TODO: Choose a worksheet more intelligently based on your
    // app's needs.
    WorksheetFeed worksheetFeed = service.getFeed(
        spreadsheet.getWorksheetFeedUrl(), WorksheetFeed.class);
    List<WorksheetEntry> worksheets = worksheetFeed.getEntries();
    WorksheetEntry worksheet = worksheets.get(0);

    // Fetch the cell feed of the worksheet.
    URL cellFeedUrl = worksheet.getCellFeedUrl();
    CellFeed cellFeed = service.getFeed(cellFeedUrl, CellFeed.class);

    // Iterate through each cell, updating its value if necessary.
    // TODO: Update cell values more intelligently.
    **for (CellEntry cell : feed.getEntries()) {**
      if (cell.getTitle().getPlainText().equals("A1")) {
        cell.changeInputValueLocal("200");
        cell.update();
      } else if (cell.getTitle().getPlainText().equals("B1")) {
        cell.changeInputValueLocal("=SUM(A1, 200)");
        cell.update();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

I've never used the Google Spreadsheets API, but the line you've highlighted has an error which is fairly clear to me.

Your variable `feed` is a `SpreadsheetFeed`.  As you have a number of 'feed' objects, for spreadsheets, worksheets and cells, it would perhaps be an idea to rename `feed` to `spreadsheetFeed`, so it is clear which type of feed it is.  You're already doing this with worksheets (`worksheetFeed`) and cells (`cellFeed`), so why not spreadsheets as well?

If you do that, the line of code you've highlighted above then becomes

```
for (CellEntry cell : spreadsheetFeed.getEntries()) {
```

Hopefully by now the error is obvious.  I'm guessing you wanted

```
for (CellEntry cell : cellFeed.getEntries()) {
```

instead.